# Is iPhone Proximity detection possible with Bluetooth? But only to obtain the MAC address of the device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I need to know the MAC address or bluetooth device name of other devices near an iPhone. is this possible with the regular API?

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 5 on the iPhone 4S, it is possible to detect Bluetooth Low Energy devices (which hardly exist yet). It's not possible with regular APIs. You can use BTstack.org if you consider Jailbreaking your device.